# How can I programmatically get the app token of an application that I create?

Tags: php, api, podio

I am using the podio-php api to create an application, however the application that I dynamically create requires a webhook. Since the webhook requires the app_id and app_token of the app, how would I be able to programmatically retrieve the app_token? (I have already contacted support to apply for access, they redirected me to the podio stackoverflow tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the token from [Get app API method in Podio](https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-area-22349). But you need special privilege for your API Client/Secret to do that. For normal API Client the token field will be empty. You can get the special privilege to your Client Id by writing to Podio.

Comment: Non programming note: the increase of trust level necessary for this operation is only granted to *trusted* companies and individuals, e.g. partners, and the _verification_ is done by our customer care team.